# is it possible to use dart with jsp?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am using spring framework for my java enterprise application .
I felt javascript / jquery is hard to maintain for larger enterprise application.
Classes and Objects makes code maintenance easier.
how can i use dart with spring framework / JSP?.

Comment: Create Dart project, compile with Dart2JS, integrate resulting JS file into your JavaEE application. Or did I miss something there? :]

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code can be generate with JSP. However, we cannot debug with Dart Editor anymore.
It would be nice and more encourage people to start to use Dart by just by support debugging a  HTML with dart from non-standard dart editor debug server.

For example: The HTML part is served by a Jetty server which contains links to dart
and we should be able to debug in Dart Editor.
Personally, This is the most needed feature otherwise, it's difficult to ask people to migrate old sytem with JSP, PHP to start to use Dart

We are listening to Dartian reponse.

I found one issue in Dart issue list: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3748

Comment: The issue is fixed. You should be able to debug. You need a custom launch configuration in DartEditor.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use dart with springframework and JSP is to create rich client app (RCP) in dart and use springframework and JSP for implementing a service layer that should be used by the RCP.

There are various disadvantages if you chose to mix the application state between the client (browser) and the server. Much more scalable model is to build on service oriented architecture (SOA) and keep the UI logic solely on the client side.

Hope it helps ;-)